# Auth0 JWT with Java

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

I implemented JSON Web Tokens using this library [Aut0 Java JWT](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) for my REST API which uses the Spring Framework.

Here is the code

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTCreationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class JWTutils {
    private final static String secret = "fj32Jfv02Mq33g0f8ioDkw";

    public static String createToken(String email)
    {
        try {
            return JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .withClaim("email", email)
                    .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256(secret));
        } catch (JWTCreationException exception){
            throw new RuntimeException("You need to enable Algorithm.HMAC256");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String getEmailInToken(String token)
    {
        try {
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(secret))
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .build();
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
            return jwt.getClaim("email").asString();
        } catch (JWTDecodeException exception){
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is my JWT secure as long as I use HTTPS? Should I use expiration dates?

Comment: Define "secure".  i.e. what threat model are you attempting to secure against?

Comment: It will be a public application, so the possible threats are people being able to generate a token based on the email address (which is public to some of the users). If I had to reformulate the question, I would say "Is my usage of the library right and is SHA256 unbreakable?"

Comment: Token encryption is only for those, who know the secret key. Your header and body will be encrypted with base64, and can be decrypted very easy. Jwt is not the way to encrypt your data, it is creation of some signature for verification, which based on header + body + secret_key

Answer (score 1):

Yes & No!, your code seems to be OK!

JWT is to put something encrypted in client's computer(like cookies) and then it is the ticket for your api.(We usually use jwt in OAuth )

You can make sure that your data in client's computer has not been modified. Then it is excellent option for small distributed session management.

**Should I use expiration dates?**

Yes especially for session management.You don't want a user to be logined forever and maybe another user be able to steal his session.This token is now his username & password. Be careful about this!

**Is it secure?!**

Security has constraints and one important one is time.Every password is breakable but in its time.You'd better change your secret once in a while.

Though Your code seems to be secure but there are many other circumstances that hacker can break into your system and get your secret. You should be aware about them too.All parts of your code including your system must have acceptable security level.
Remember:

**A chain is only as strong as its weakest link**

Answer (score 0):

To say simply in context of your curiosity "It is not secure". Because JWT is not to pass secure data.

Basically JWT is to use to protect 'MODIFICATION' your data that you provided to others or from channel. You give then a data with a signature. And when your provided data returned back from them, you can check your data MODIFIED-OR-NOT by that Signature.

On the the other hand your provided data is public, anyone can see your Payload-Data by Base64 decoder. So you should not pass plain password over JWT at all.